# Image not showing in a JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jlabel

I have just started learning java GUI and I have a lot of problems with the images. I looked through multiple topics on this site and others too, but for some reason I cannot get this to work (though I am probably making a lot of mistakes and I just don't realise it). I just want to start with showing an image on the screen. To add some information - I am using IntelliJ; the image is stored in a resource folder that I have marked as a "library root" (also, the image is pretty small - 16x16, but I have also tried with a bigger image and it doesn't help me).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Frame {

    public static final int WIDTH = 1024;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 768;

    public Frame()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Shady Path");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        //Font font = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 10);
        JLabel human = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/human.jpg")));
        Dimension humanDimension = new Dimension(150, 150);
        human.setMinimumSize(humanDimension);
        human.setPreferredSize(humanDimension);
        human.setMaximumSize(humanDimension);
        human.setLocation(100, 100);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(human);
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any runtime errors? Or is it opening the window and is just not displaying any images

Comment: Try doing human.setSize(), null layout doesn't care about preferred or min. sizes

Comment: There aren't any runtime errors, it just shows the black frame;

Comment: human.setSize() doesn't change anything, but still thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set your layout to null.

Comment: the real herohere